# dispatch touch events from gesture listener onSingleTapConfirmed and keep selector effects

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-event

I have a list view with items containing multiple buttons. The layout for one item looks something like this:

[image: The black frame represents one listview item]

I have an overlaying transparent view, covering each entire list item. This view listens to two gestures: `onDoubleTap` and `onSingleTapConfimred`.

To trigger the click listeners on the underlying buttons i can just dispatch the touch events from the overlaying touch listener, but this **does not** show the selectors and states on the buttons (for example changed background color on press). I also only want the trigger click events when the overlaying view has fired `onSingleTapConfimred`

```
...
final DtGestureDetector detector = new DtGestureDetector(position);
final GestureDetector gd = new GestureDetector(convertView.getContext(), detector);
postViewHolder.viewOverlay.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {           
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        //i want to trigger this only onSingleTapConfirmed and set the view selector on touch
        //postViewHolder.txtMessage.onTouchEvent(event); 
        //postViewHolder.layPhoto.onTouchEvent(event);
        gd.onTouchEvent(event);                     
        return true;
    }
});
...
private class DtGestureDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private int position;   

    public DtGestureDetector(int position) {
        super();
        this.position = position;
    }

    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.d(tag, "DoubleTap"+position);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.d(tag, "SingleTap"+position);
            return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this by setting state programmatically

```
int[] state = new int[] {android.R.attr.state_window_focused, android.R.attr.state_focused};
drawable.setState(state);
```